# Guice + Конфигурация приложения

Tags: java, dependency-injection

Добрый день, подскажите есть ли более object-oriented, чем @Named аннотации, способ вставлять данные из файла конфигурации в классы при помощи google guice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот  Вам вариант который я писал сам для себя... [guice-config](https://bitbucket.org/strangerintheq/guice-config/wiki/Home)

Comment: Получается что каждой записи в конфиге соответствует значение в enum?

Comment: Да, так и есть, с точностью до uppercase и замены точки на знак нижнего подчеркивания

Comment: Спасибо, это то, что нужно!